# How do I use BehaviorSubject class to redirect user on homepage after logging in, it doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am developing an IONIC 4 app, and want to authenticate user before they can go to homepage. How do I avoid login screen flickering after successful authentication?

This is an IONIC 4 app, with angular 6 support. I am using storage to save JWT token to avoid user going to login screen each time they run the application.

app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'home', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' }
```

app.component.ts

```
this.authenticationService.authenticationState.subscribe(state => {
    if (state) {
      console.log("inside if, state=" + state);
      this.router.navigate(['home'], {skipLocationChange: true});
    } else {
      console.log("inside else, state=" + state);
      this.router.navigate(['signup1'], {skipLocationChange: true});
    }
  });
```

authentication.service.ts

```
const TOKEN_KEY = 'auth-token';

authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(private storage: Storage, private plt: Platform) {
this.plt.ready().then(() => {
  this.checkToken();
});
  }
   checkToken() {
this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY).then(res => {
  if (res) {
    this.authenticationState.next(true);
  }
})
 }
isAuthenticated() {
return this.authenticationState.value;
  }
login() {
return this.storage.set(TOKEN_KEY, 'Bearer 1234567').then(() => {
  this.authenticationState.next(true);
});
 }
```

auth-gaurd.service.ts

```
 canActivate(): boolean {
return this.auth.isAuthenticated();
 }
```

The app should redirect user to home page after getting JWT token in storage without displaying login page. However, it flickers login screen and then redirects to homepage.

Please check the output on my device

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qz_1ExUB1d_I0r71sQ2sX1F4RFC5680E/view?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i got, so you can try to change your subject to

```
authenticationState = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

and in component:

```
this.authenticationService.authenticationState.filter(x => x !== null).take(1).subscribe(...)
```

or using pipe

```
this.authenticationService.authenticationState.pipe(
   filter(x => x !== null),
   take(1)
).subscribe(...)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Amir, Thanks for your answer.

I made the changes, however it doesn't solve the problem when I log out.

    this.authenticationService.authenticationState.pipe(filter(x => x !== null),take(1)).subscribe(state => {
          console.log("inside if, state=" + state);
          if(state)
          {
            this.router.navigate(['home'], {skipLocationChange: true});
          }
          else
          {
            this.router.navigate(['signup1'], {skipLocationChange: true});
          }
      });

Anything I do is not working the way I want. Am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: What do you mean, when you log out what happens?

Comment: Try to remove **take(1),**

Comment: When logged in, BehaviorSubject is not null that means its set to true. Then it works and app opens the homepage. But once, I logout using following method.

logout() {
    return this.storage.remove(TOKEN_KEY).then(() => {
      this.authenticationState.next(null);
    });
  }

I am setting the BehaviorSubject value back to null when logout. Then, it should redirect to signup page. But it doesn't, because filter(x => x !== null) condition doesn't satisfy. 

Even if i check filter(x => x == null) again and redirect the app to sign up page. The previous issue shows up.

Comment: Previous issue, signup page flickers and then home page is shown.

Comment: I had followed this tutorial - https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-login-angular/    even the tutor couldn't figure why the login page flickers before redirection. LOL